# How to update existing notification on Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, push-notification, windows-phone

My app sends a push notification to users hourly.

But if the user isn't connected to the internet or didn't open the notification they get more and more notifications.

Is there any way of remove old notifications when new one arrives?
Or update the existing one with the new data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try to set the same group or tag in your toast notifications. That should tell notification center that you want to replace old one with the new one.

Please look at examples here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn631260.aspx

Comment: At first I was worried that it would be available only to 8.1, but I realized that there was no notification center prior to 8.1